# how much information $O_K$ points of a formal scheme over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ contain

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, formal-schemes

assume that $Spf\,A\to Spf\,\mathbb{Z}_p[[t_1,...,t_n]]$ is a closed immersion of flat integral formal schemes over $\mathbb{Z_p}$. I see Kisin several time use that if $Spf\,A(O_K)\subset SPf\,\mathbb{Z}_p[[t_1,...,t_k]](O_K)$ inside $\mathbb{Z}_p[[t_1,...,t_n]]$ for every finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. then the map $Spf\,A\to Spf\,\mathbb{Z}_p[[t_1,...,t_n]]$ factors through $SPf\,\mathbb{Z}_p[[t_1,...,t_k]]$.

why is this true? the best thing I can get is that all characteristic Zero points of codimension one of
$Spf\, A$ must be in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[t_1,...,t_k]]$

Comment: I am sorry but I am having trouble understanding your question. How is $\mathcal{O}_K$ a $\mathbf{Z}_p$-algebra? Can you give a reference to the argument used by Kisin? Also, you misspelled Kisin.

Comment: In any case, $A = \mathbf{Z}_p[[t_1, \ldots, t_n]]/I$ for some prime ideal $I$. You want to show that $t_i\in I$ for $i=k+1, \ldots, n$. So you need to show that for every nonzero $f\in A$ there exists a surjection $\phi\colon A\to \mathcal{O}_K$ for $K$ a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ (is that the intended meaning?) such that $\phi(f)\neq 0$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger sorry I fixed the typos. I see this fact several time  used in the two papers of Kisin about Langlands-Rapaport  conjecture in good reduction case. thank for your hint I guess we know this after inverting $p$ and then we use a compactness argument right?